# Add class on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Below is my code used to show the content on click (like accordion). Content is displaying on clicking on "a" tag. So How do I add bgcolor as white for clicked "a" tag .

HTML

```
<ul class="accordion">
        <li>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="336" class="name">lorem</td>
                    <td width="101" class="info current" idcust="tr1" custdata="#cnt1"><a href="#">test</a></td>
                    <td width="107" class="info" idcust="tr1" custdata="#cnt2"><a href="#">test2</a></td>
                    <td width="102" class="info" idcust="tr1" custdata="#cnt3"><a href="#">test2</a></td>
                    <td width="104" class="info" idcust="tr1" custdata="#cnt4"><a href="#">test2</a></td>
                    <td width="100" class="info" idcust="tr1" custdata="#cnt5"><a href="#">test2</a></td>
                    <td width="100" class="info" idcust="tr1" custdata="#cnt6"><a href="#">test2</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr class="cntetn" customid="tab_content">
                    <td colspan="7" id="tr1">
                      <span id="cnt1"><p>content here</p></span>
                      <span id="cnt2"><p>content here</p></p></span>
    <span id="cnt3"><p>content here</p></p></span>
    <span id="cnt4"><p>content here</p></p></span>
    <span id="cnt5"><p>content here</p></p></span>
    <span id="cnt6"><p>content here</p></p></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
            $('ul').accordion();
             $(".info").find("a").click(function(){
            var trid = $(this).parent().attr("idcust");                
            var trdata = $(this).parent().attr("custdata");
            // Hide all content divs and show only the one related to the click
            $("#"+trid).children().hide();
            $(trdata).show();
            $("#"+trid).toggle();
        });
        });
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930738/add-class-on-click ?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl That question was removed.

Comment: yup. current page is real one

Comment: @irrelephant: Cool, just at the time I saw this question I was able to load both of them :) Now the last one is gone. Must have been a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use addClass:

```
$(".info").find("a").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('white_class');
     ...
```

when an `a` tag is clicked

CSS:

```
.white_class{
     background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: @Sowmya the class must be specified in css style

Comment: Pls check this fiddle. It is not working in this case http://jsfiddle.net/mHqnF/1/

Comment: That's because `.info a` has a `background:none !important;`. And `.accordion a` has a background too.

Comment: Oh yes..!! thank you.. And one more thing is, the click which is opening the content should be switchable, like if on second click the previous content should be closed and the new one should be opened. Presently i need to click 2 times to get rid of 1st tab.

Answer (score 1):

> $(this).css({'background-color' : '#FFF'});

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by two ways

1) `$("a").attr("background-color","White");`

2) make a css class

```
.bgcolr{
 background-color:white;
}
```

and

```
$("a").addClass("bgcolr");
```